# Combining multiple pipeable NgRx selectors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

Is it possible to combine multiple [*pipeable* selectors](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#advanced-usage) the same way we can combine multiple regular selectors?

Combining regular selectors:

```js
export const selectActiveOrganization = createSelector(
    selectOrganizations,
    selectActiveOrganizationId,
    (organizations, activeOrgId) => organizations[activeOrgId],
);
```

Above there are two selectors `selectOrganizations` and `selectActiveOrganizationId`, which are passed into `createSelector` to create a `selectActiveOrganization`.

Problem here is that `selectActiveOrganization` can also return `undefined`.

---

Now let's rewrite this to **pipeable** selector:

```js
const _selectActiveOrganization = createSelector(
    selectOrganizations,
    selectActiveOrganizationId,
    (organizations, activeOrgId) => organizations[activeOrgId],
);

export const selectActiveOrganizationPipeable = pipe(
    select(_selectActiveOrganization),
    filter(activeOrg => !!activeOrg),
);
```

In `selectActiveOrganizationPipeable` we improved the `selectActiveOrganization` selector to only emit value if there is any active organization.

So far so good.

Now let's say we want to build on to of our pipeable selector and create a new one which is returning only the organization name.

```js
export const selectActiveOrganizationNamePipeable = pipe(
    select(selectActiveOrganizationPipeable),
    map(organization => organization.name), // --> TS ERROR: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Observable<Organization>'.ts(2339)
);
```

Is there a way to reuse existing `selectActiveOrganizationPipeable`? (similarly as we reuse regular selectors)

Comment: Does it work if you remove the 'select' inside the pipe? `selectActiveOrganizationNamePipeable = pipe(selectActiveOrganizationPipeable, map(organization => organization.name));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.
You can use the previous pipe within the new pipe.

```
export const selectActiveOrganizationNamePipeable = 
  pipe(
    selectActiveOrganizationPipeable,
    map(organization => organization.name)
  );
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? Isn't that going absolutely against the idea of selectors which is to have a synchronous function, memoized for perfs etc? Why just not create a new selector that returns the organization name?

Comment: I understand that you probably just answered what OP is asking but I think it should be worth pointing that it is a bad idea because from there this "selector" cannot be reused by other selectors as it'll be an observable.

Comment: I think it actually goes along with DRY principle, because if you do create another selector to return organization name you still have to do the check if active organization is not undefined. But this check is already done in `selectActiveOrganizationPipeable` so why not to reuse it? And memoization is still there because `_selectActiveOrganization` is created by `createSelector()`.